# Show related documents based on a tag column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

In the document library I defined a new column (multi-value) choice field for tagging the document. Than I added a SharePoint Online page --> added the document library web part on page and configured it so that only a special folder will be shown.

Below that web part I want to show related documents with the similar tags. I tried it with the highlight content web part where I can use CAML queries but without success. The problem here is that I cannot set dynamic search terms from my web part above.

Has anybody an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To filter library documents based on a column using highlighted content web part KQL/CAML query, the column has to be mapped to a managed property. You can take a reference to my answer in this thread: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/408476/how-to-filter-sharepoint-online-queries-kql-docume.html